# How to delete all cookies in safari 5.1.3 on osx lion

Tags: safari

I am trying to remove all cookies in safari 5.1.3.  In firefox/chrome this is controlled by command+shift+delete

In safari I have tried preferences->privacy->Remove all website data.  But this is NOT deleting all cookies despite what it says, Ok so doing this deletes stack exchange cookies but it still leaves me logged in to gmail.

Does anyone know why gmail cookies still stay despite safari saying i am deleting google cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Safari](http://www.apple.com/safari/features.html)

> Privacy Pane 
>   A new Privacy pane in Safari preferences gives you more
>   control over your online privacy, allowing you to clear website data,
>   customize cookie settings, and choose whether websites can request
>   your location information.

This is also a [known issue](http://macography.net/2012/01/how-to-watch-html5-youtube-videos-full-screen-in-safari/) in some versions of Safari when working with the YouTube HTML5 Beta.

Since it is not a Safari or OS X issue, you may want to try other browsers like  [FireFox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/) or [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome).

Lastly, Always make sure OS X is updated along with Safari. Safari is currently at 5.1.5 right now. [Here is how to update](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1338)